# Create ILookup<int,int> from IDictionary<int,IEnumerable<int>>

Tags: c#

Is there any elegant way how to transform

`IDictionary<int, IEnumerable<int>>` into `ILookup<int,int>` ?
As far as I know it should be identical, but I find lookups to be more clear.

Story behind this is more complex but I'm forced to select List of ids together with its Lists of related ids:

```
masters
    .Select(m => new {masterId = m.Id, childIds = m.Children.Select(c => c.Id)})
    .ToDictionary(k => masterId, v => v.childIds)
```

I would be happy to select directly Lookup but I don't know if its possible.

example of master variable type can be simple as this:

```
public class Master
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public List<Master> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `ToLookup` is used to convert a flat list into groups - you already _have_ groups, so what do you need a lookup for?  And what do you need a `lookup` for that your `Dictionary` doesn't give you?

Comment: There should be no *practical* difference between a dictionary of enumerables and a lookup; so you don’t get any benefits by converting it into a lookup.

Comment: Are you thinking of something like this? `masters.ToLookup(m => m.Id, m => m.Children.Select(c => c.Id));`

Comment: @Chips_100 That will create a lookup from the id to an enumerable of enumerables of child ids.

Comment: Do you need the `Select`? It looks like you can just do: `masters.ToDictionary(m => m.Id, m => m.Children.Select(c => c.Id));`

Comment: I'm fully aware of no practical difference. I just wonder if there is way to create Lookup from Dictionary which is less readable in case that values are Lists. As I said, story behind is more complex, I'm using structured data from DB and processing them in memory..

Comment: Then the answer is simply: no, there is no way to convert between one and another. They are fundamentally different albeit very similar when used. If you wanted to convert your dictionary to a lookup, you would have to flatten it, and then group it again which would be throwing away all the information about your index and require building it again. And that means a bad performance.

Comment: Have you considered just creating a wrapper class, one that wraps around that dictionary and implements the lookup interface on top of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Lasse V. Karlsen suggested in the comments, you could create a wrapper type that exposes an `ILookup`:

```
public class LookupDictionary<TKey, TElement> : ILookup<TKey, TElement>
{
    private readonly IDictionary<TKey, IEnumerable<TElement>> _dic;

    public LookupDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, IEnumerable<TElement>> dic)
    {
        _dic = dic;
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _dic.Values.Sum(x => x.Count()); }
    }

    public IEnumerable<TElement> this[TKey key]
    {
        get { return _dic.ContainsKey(key) ? _dic[key] : Enumerable.Empty<TElement>(); }
    }

    public bool Contains(TKey key)
    {
        return _dic.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public IEnumerator<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _dic.Select(kv => new LookupDictionaryGrouping(kv)).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    class LookupDictionaryGrouping : IGrouping<TKey, TElement>
    {
        private KeyValuePair<TKey, IEnumerable<TElement>> _kvp;

        public TKey Key
        {
            get { return _kvp.Key; }
        }

        public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _kvp.Value.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }

        public LookupDictionaryGrouping(KeyValuePair<TKey, IEnumerable<TElement>> kvp)
        {
            _kvp = kvp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My -1: The biggest difference between Lookups and Dictionaries of Lists is that Lookups return an Empty Enumerable when you request a key that doesn't exist instead of throwing an exception.  This implementation doesn't honor that contract.

Comment: @afrazier I was not aware of that, and looking at the ILookup documentation, it’s also not part of the interface but an implementation detail of the Lookup type. But sure, one can easily add that.

Comment: From [Lookup<TKey, TElement>.Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb292716%28v=vs.100%29.aspx): `If the key is not found in the collection, an empty sequence is returned.`  Edit: I see that the interface documentation doesn't specify that.  Strange.

Comment: `DictionaryLookup` would be a better name.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you *could* flatten the dictionary and *then* convert it to a `Lookup`:

```
dict.SelectMany(kvp -> kvp.Value, (kvp, v) => new {k = kvp.Key, v})
    .ToLookup(kvp => kvp.k, kvp => kvp.v)
```

but it's practically the same thing as a dictionary so it seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to flatten your collection. You can do it like this:

```
masters.SelectMany(x => x.Children, (x, y) 
   => new { 
            ParentId = x.Id, 
            ChildId = y.Id 
          })
   .ToLookup(x => x.ParentId, y => y.ChildId);
```

So you'll get your `ILookup<int,int>`. Moreover, you don't need any `Dictionary` collection. But it' pretty much safe with `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this - a bit more readable than pure lambdas... :)

```
Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<int>> dict = new Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<int>>();

dict.Add(1, new int[] {1, 2, 3});
dict.Add(2, new int[] {4, 5, 6});
dict.Add(3, new int[] {4, 5, 6});

var lookup = (from kv in dict
            from v in kv.Value
            select new KeyValuePair<int, int>(kv.Key, v)).ToLookup(k=>k.Key, v=>v.Value);
```